# NodeJS: Why does new Date().toLocaleString() ignore the system timezone?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My /etc/timezone is set to my local time zone and this is the output from "timedatectl status":

```
      Local time: Wed 2018-09-26 12:01:32 MDT
  Universal time: Wed 2018-09-26 18:01:32 UTC
        RTC time: Wed 2018-09-26 18:01:32
       Time zone: Etc/UTC (MDT, -0600)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

The "date" command prints Wed Sep 26:12:01:32 MDT 2018.

In Node, "new Date().toLocaleString()" ignores the timezone and spits out "2018-09-26 18:01:32".

Is there a way to get the local time in Node? All the answers I've seen so far claim that Node is unable to determine the timezone of the machine it's running on unless you explicitly set a "TZ" environment variable, which is ridiculous.

Comment: Sounds like you already found your answer? Probably node doesn't need this feature because most server applications don't care about the timezone they're hosted in. So your solutions seem limited to a) use that ridiculous environment variable b) automate that environment variable to read your system config c) submit a patch to node.js to take the system timezone into account

Comment: Doing more digging it seems that Node doesn't concern itself with the timezone at all; V8 just makes system calls to localtime(3) so TZ is getting checked by Linux. (None of this stuff works the same on Windows.)

Comment: Also found an interesting link explaining how setting TZ improves the performance of time/date POSIX calls systemwide on Linux: https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2017/02/21/set-environment-variable-save-thousands-of-system-calls/ So TZ isn't as ridiculous as I thought, but the fact that this is only an issue on Linux elicited my WTF reaction.